# Why $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(\bar{z})^2}{z^2}$ doesn't exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Why this limit does not exist?

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(\bar{z})^2}{z^2}$$

I know that the limit exists and equals to $1$ is $z$ is real. When $z$ is complex, I tried

$$\frac{(\bar{z})^2}{z^2}=\frac{e^{-2i\theta}}{e^{2i\theta}}=e^{-4i\theta}$$

Then put the limit back,

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{(\bar{z})^2}{z^2}=\lim_{z\to0} e^{-4i\theta}$$

Then I got a little bit confused because I wasn't sure if $\lim_{z\to 0}$ is equivalent to $\lim_{r\to 0}$? I was thinking something like "$z$ gets small iif $\|z\|$ gets small iif $r$ gets small".

Comment: So, the limit in different directions do not agree.  This means, the limit itself does not exist.

Comment: You pretty much already answered. The limit depends on $\theta$, you should have a theorem that says that when a limit exists, it is unique. But you got a whole bunch of them.